# How to use generics in usercontrol code behind

Tags: c#, generics, razor

I want to a add function to the code behind my usercontrol which looks like this:

```
public IDictionary<string, object> GetHtmlAttributes(object fixedHtmlAttributes = null,
    IDictionary<string, object> dynamicHtmlAttributes = null)
{
    var attributes = (fixedHtmlAttributes == null)
        ? new RouteValueDictionary()
        : HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(fixedHtmlAttributes);

    if (dynamicHtmlAttributes != null)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in dynamicHtmlAttributes)
        {
            attributen[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
        }
    }
    return attributes;
}
```

When I try to introduce generics here like below, the compiler throws me an error that it `Cannot resolve symbol T`:

```
public IDictionary<string, T> GetHtmlAttributes(object fixedHtmlAttributes = null,
    IDictionary<string, T> dynamicHtmlAttributes = null)
```

Is it even possible?

Comment: `public IDictionary<string, T> GetHtmlAttributes<T>(object ....`?

Comment: Doh! You're totally right, thanks for your answer